# Ajax Pipeline - Server Side doesn`t work for me

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables, pager

At first i get the css, the datatables.js and afterwards i start with the ajax pipelining code and after all i initialize it - here it is:

```
<link href="tablesorter/tablesortingStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="tablesorter/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
    $.fn.dataTable.pipeline = function ( opts ) {
            var conf = $.extend( {
                    pages: 5,    
                    url: '',    
                    data: null,
                    method: 'GET'
            }, opts );
            var cacheLower = -1;
            var cacheUpper = null;
            var cacheLastRequest = null;
            var cacheLastJson = null;
     
            return function ( request, drawCallback, settings ) {
                    var ajax          = false;
                    var requestStart  = request.start;
                    var drawStart     = request.start;
                    var requestLength = request.length;
                    var requestEnd    = requestStart + requestLength;
                     
                    if ( settings.clearCache ) {
                            ajax = true;
                            settings.clearCache = false;
                    }
                    else if ( cacheLower < 0 || requestStart < cacheLower || requestEnd   > cacheUpper ) {
                            ajax = true;
                    }
                    else if ( JSON.stringify( request.order )   !== JSON.stringify( cacheLastRequest.order ) ||
                                      JSON.stringify( request.columns ) !==   JSON.stringify( cacheLastRequest.columns ) ||
                                      JSON.stringify( request.search )  !==    JSON.stringify( cacheLastRequest.search )
                    ) {
                            ajax = true;
                    }
                    cacheLastRequest = $.extend( true, {}, request );
                    if ( ajax ) {
                            if ( requestStart < cacheLower ) {
                                    requestStart = requestStart - (requestLength*   (conf.pages-1));
     
                                    if ( requestStart < 0 ) {
                                            requestStart = 0;
                                    }
                            }
                            cacheLower = requestStart;
                            cacheUpper = requestStart + (requestLength * conf.pages);
                            request.start = requestStart;
                            request.length = requestLength*conf.pages;
                            if ( $.isFunction ( conf.data ) ) {
                                    var d = conf.data( request );
                                    if ( d ) {
                                            $.extend( request, d );
                                    }
                            }
                            else if ( $.isPlainObject( conf.data ) ) {
                                    $.extend( request, conf.data );
                            }
                            settings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
                                    "type":     conf.method,
                                    "url":      conf.url,
                                    "data":     request,
                                    "dataType": "json",
                                    "cache":    false,
                                    "success":  function ( json ) {
                                            cacheLastJson = $.extend(true, {}, json);
     
                                            if ( cacheLower != drawStart ) {
                                                    json.data.splice( 0, drawStart-  cacheLower );
                                            }
                                            json.data.splice( requestLength,    json.data.length );
                                             
                                            drawCallback( json );
                                    }
                            } );
                    }
                    else {
                            json = $.extend( true, {}, cacheLastJson );
                            json.draw = request.draw;
                            json.data.splice( 0, requestStart-cacheLower );
                            json.data.splice( requestLength, json.data.length );
     
                            drawCallback(json);
                    }
            }
    };
    $.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'clearPipeline()', function () {
            return this.iterator( 'table', function ( settings ) {
                    settings.clearCache = true;
            } );
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
            // Login-Logs-Tabelle, wird mit DataTables initialisiert
            $('#mylogins').dataTable({
                    "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "language": {
                            "emptyTable":     "Keine Daten verfügbar.",
                            "info":           "Zeige _START_ bis _END_ von _TOTAL_ Einträgen",
                            "infoEmpty":      "Zeige 0 bis 0 von 0 Einträgen",
                            "infoFiltered":   "(gefiltert von _MAX_ insgesamten Einträgen)",
                            "infoPostFix":    "",
                            "thousands":      ",",
                            "lengthMenu":     "Zeige _MENU_ Einträge",
                            "loadingRecords": "Lade...",
                            "processing":     "Wird verarbeitet...",
                            "search":         "Suche:",
                            "zeroRecords":    "Keine passenden Einträge gefunden",
                            "paginate": {
                                    "first":      "Erste",
                                    "last":       "Letzte",
                                    "next":       "Nächste",
                                    "previous":   "Vorherige"
                            },
                            "aria": {
                                    "sortAscending":  ": Aktivieren, um die Spalte aufsteigend zu sortieren",
                                    "sortDescending": ": Aktivieren, um die Spalte     absteigend zu sortieren"
                            }
                    },
                    "ajax": $.fn.dataTable.pipeline({
                            url: 'tablesorter/serverside/loginlogs.php',
                            pages: 5 // Seiten die gecached werden
                    })
            });
    });
</script>
```

My serverside script is like that:

```
<?php
// Datenbank-Tabelle, die verwendet wird
$table = 'loginlogs';

// Der Primary key, der Tabelle
$primaryKey = 'id';

// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
// parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple indexes.
$columns = array(
array( 'db' => 'ip', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array(
    'db'        => 'status',
    'dt'        => 1,
    'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
        if($d == 1){
                            return "Erfolgreich";
                    }else{
                            return "Fehlgeschlagen";
                    }
    }
),
    array(
    'db'        => 'stayloggedin',
    'dt'        => 2,
    'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
                    if($d == 1){
                            return "Ja";
                    }else{
                            return "Nein";
                    }
    }
),
array(
    'db'        => 'date',
    'dt'        => 3,
    'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
                    return getonlydate($d);
    }
),
    array(
    'db'        => 'date',
    'dt'        => 4,
    'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
                    return getonlytime($d);
    }
)
);

// SQL server connection information
require('../../phpfuncs/connection.php');
$sql_details = array(
'user' => $user,
'pass' => $pw,
'db'   => $db,
'host' => $host
);


require('ssp.class.php');

echo json_encode(
SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
?>
```

So i have my css, js and the serverside(php) part... .
What is my mistake?
I get no error in the console and it is freezed in the processing part.
I watched the network analyzer part and it has been stopped so there is nothing, where the script is trying to get or load.
Can somebody please help me?

By the way here is my debug log:
http://debug.datatables.net/urifuz

I use on my test server, PHP Version 5.5.11

## Edit:

I couldn't edit my post yesterday, because stackoverflow was only in a readable mode. So now i do it. I solved the problem. I used two functions in the serverside part, where i need to include my functions.php. For my bad the console didn`t recognize that and so there were no errors. But no i included the functions and all works fine.

Comment: Please add the code into the question and not from an external source.

Comment: now it is like you wished - maybe you give me now a answer, which is more helpfully?^^